# Getting call history returns only last 20 logs

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

```cs
PhoneCallHistoryStore store = await PhoneCallHistoryManager.RequestStoreAsync(PhoneCallHistoryStoreAccessType.AllEntriesLimitedReadWrite);
PhoneCallHistoryEntryQueryOptions options = new PhoneCallHistoryEntryQueryOptions() { DesiredMedia = PhoneCallHistoryEntryQueryDesiredMedia.All };
PhoneCallHistoryEntryReader reader = store.GetEntryReader(options);
var logs = await reader.ReadBatchAsync();
```

Here `logs.Count` is always 20.

How can I get all the logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's the correct behavior. In method's name you can see `Batch`. It means that you take part of calls (20 items). For getting all calls use the following code:

```cs
    PhoneCallHistoryStore store = await PhoneCallHistoryManager.RequestStoreAsync(PhoneCallHistoryStoreAccessType.AllEntriesLimitedReadWrite);
    PhoneCallHistoryEntryQueryOptions options = new PhoneCallHistoryEntryQueryOptions() { DesiredMedia = PhoneCallHistoryEntryQueryDesiredMedia.All };
    PhoneCallHistoryEntryReader reader = store.GetEntryReader(options);
    var phoneCallHistoryEntries = new List<PhoneCallHistoryEntry>();

    var hasItems = true;
    do
    {
        var logs = await reader.ReadBatchAsync();
        phoneCallHistoryEntries.AddRange(logs);
        hasItems = logs.Count > 0;
    }
    while (hasItems);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for confirming it. I actually already tried it calling again, but don't know how I got the same result again. After reading your answer I tried again, and it worked.