# Retrieve last call history entry in UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I want to retrieve the last call history entry in a Windows 10 mobile app (UWP), and I can do it with a high cost approach like below.

```cs
PhoneCallHistoryStore phoneCallHistoryStore = await PhoneCallHistoryManager.RequestStoreAsync(PhoneCallHistoryStoreAccessType.AllEntriesLimitedReadWrite);
PhoneCallHistoryEntryReader phoneCallHistoryEntryReader = phoneCallHistoryStore.GetEntryReader();
IReadOnlyList<PhoneCallHistoryEntry> phoneCallHistoryEntries = await phoneCallHistoryEntryReader.ReadBatchAsync();
PhoneCallHistoryEntry lastPhoneCallHistoryEntry = phoneCallHistoryEntries.FirstOrDefault();
```

As you know and describe in [Getting call history returns only last 20 logs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36107562/1539100) this approach per run retrieves 20 calls when I only want the last call, so I think I am paying a high cost for this and I retrieve 19 call unnecessarily.

Is there any better approach?

Comment: What does "ITNOA" stand for? What are your performance goals, and how far away is the current API from meeting those goas?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT thx for your response, I think if I can get last call history without get 20 call histories is better than top approach. I ask this question to find a better approach to get call history if exists.

Comment: I think it is good if I can directly query into PhoneCallHistoryStore. and apply custom filter for retrieve exact call history result instead of I retrieve all call history and then filter it. It cause to performance improvement. however this subject does not have directly relevance with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting a "batch" of calls at a time is the only way to get entries. If you think the method is too slow, you can provide feedback via the Feedback Hub's "Developer" category. But before you decide it is too slow, you need to define what "fast enough" is for your scenario, then measure the code against your goals with a profiler, and verify the slowness it's cause by this API (vs something else).